# apache2 FastCGI comm with dynamic server aborted first read idle timeout

Tags: apache2, fastcgi, mod-fastcgi, apache2-module, flup

**Summary:** Unable to run any of the most simple “Hello World” FastCGI script, any request always terminating into a time out. Seems there is no communication at all between the server and the FastCGI scripts (using dynamic FastCGI scripts).

## The environment

- Ubuntu Precise (12.04)
- Package `apache2.2-bin`
- Package `apache2-mpm-prefork`
- Package `libapache2-mod-fastcgi`
- Package `libfcgi-perl`
- Package `python-flup`
- Multiple sites configured as virtual hosts on `127.0.0.1`
- There exists a `/var/lib/apache2/fastcgi` directory, owned by `www-data`, readable by all (owner, group and others)
- There exists a `/var/lib/apache2/fastcgi/dynamic` directory, owned by `www-data`, which is restricted to the owner (readable, writable and accessible by `www-data` only)
- There exists an inode/socket file in the `/var/lib/apache2/fastcgi/` directory

## The FastCGI relevant configurations:

The directory `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/` holds a reference to `fastcgi.conf` and `fastcgi.load` (`mod_fastcgi` is enabled).

The file `fastcgi.conf` contains the following (left untouched, I did not edit it):

```
<IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
  AddHandler fastcgi-script .fcgi
  #FastCgiWrapper /usr/lib/apache2/suexec
  FastCgiIpcDir /var/lib/apache2/fastcgi
</IfModule>
```

The relevant configuration file in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/` contains the following (there is nothing more anywhere else about FastCGI specific configuration):

```
<DirectoryMatch /fcgi-bin>
   Options +ExecCGI
   <FilesMatch "^[^\.]+$">
      SetHandler fastcgi-script
   </FilesMatch>
</DirectoryMatch>
```

## The test materials on the test virtual host:

There exist a `fcgi-bin/test-perl.fcgi` whose content is (the file is executable by all, and readable by owner and group):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use CGI::Fast qw(:standard);
    $COUNTER = 0;
    while (new CGI::Fast) {
    print header;
    print start_html("Fast CGI Rocks");
    print
        h1("Fast CGI Rocks"),
        "Invocation number ",b($COUNTER++),
            " PID ",b($$),".",
        hr;
        print end_html;
    }
```

There exist a `fcgi-bin/test-python.fcgi` whose content is (the file is executable by all, and readable by owner and group):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

def myapp(environ, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/plain')])
    return ['Hello World!\n']

try:
    from flup.server.fcgi import WSGIServer
    WSGIServer(myapp).run()
except:
    import sys, traceback
    traceback.print_exc(file=open("errlog.txt","a"))
```

## The issue

Although both `fcgi-bin/test-perl.fcgi` and `fcgi-bin/test-python.fcgi` runs normally when executed from the command‑line, none seems to work when invoked, e.g. as `http://test.loc/fcgi-bin/test-perl.fcgi` or `http://test.loc/fcgi-bin/test-python.fcgi`.

Nothing at all happens, and after some delay, I get an Error 500, and Apache error logs contains multiple entries looking like:

```
[<date>] [error] [client <IP>] FastCGI: comm with (dynamic) server "/<…>/fcgi-bin/<script>.fcgi" aborted: (first read) idle timeout (30 sec), referer: <referrer>
[<date>] [error] [client <IP>] FastCGI: incomplete headers (0 bytes) received from server "<…>/fcgi-bin/<script>.fcgi", referer: <referrer>
```

I've spent hours and hours searching the web trying to understand why it does not work, and finally decided to give up and ask for some help here.

Any pointers and check list welcome. Feel free to ask for any missing details you may feel to be relevant or worth checking.

Enjoy a nice day.

-- edit --

## Issue update

In [my own reply to my own question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15565267/279335), I mentioned a weird case where things were looking suddenly fine without reasons. I later discovered this was only partly fine.

In the same virtual host, so with the exact same server configuration, some scripts, which are exactly the same (and with exact same access rights), fails depending on their location.

As a remainder, here is what's in the site configuration:

```
<DirectoryMatch /fcgi-bin>
   Options +ExecCGI
   <FilesMatch "^[^\.]+$">
      SetHandler fastcgi-script
   </FilesMatch>
</DirectoryMatch>
```

With the above, only scripts in `/fcgi-bin` are handled as FastCGI script. But I also have some elsewhere (still for testing): one in `/cgi-bin` and one in `/` (i.e. in the `public_html` directory). For this purpose, `.htaccess` contains this entry:

```
Options +ExecCGI
AddHandler fastcgi-script .fcgi
```

So the two others FastCGI script should work the same as the one in `/fcgi-bin`, but they don't, and for the time, they invariably terminates with a connexion time‑out, just like the one `/fcgi-bin` first did.

This makes me feel something may be wrong with the `mod_fastcgi` module (known bug? else?). So far, this module seems to act rather randomly.

-- edit 2 --

The above in the first edit, was an error of mine: the group was wrong with the other scripts, it had to be `www-data`, but it was not. So is something is wrong, stick to the answer I gave, that is, try to look at the `FastCgiConfig`, and see if it solve anything or at least if it honours the time‑out options.

Answer (score 4):

I will answer my own question, as it seems to be working now. However, the epilogue still looks weird.

Although the default configuration should be OK, I still wanted to review [the “Module mod_fastcgi” document](http://www.fastcgi.com/mod_fastcgi/docs/mod_fastcgi.html) again. As I only wanted a dynamic FastCGI, I focused on the `FastCgiConfig` directive only, thus on purpose not going into `FastCgiServer` and `FastCgiExternalServer` directives.

As there was no `FastCgiServer` at all in the default `fastcgi.conf` file, I started to try to set‑up my own. For a first test, I wanted to use the `-appConnTimeout` option, at least to request the server to not wait so much long before it returns me an Error 500.

So I just added this in the site configuration (I did not touch `fastcgi.cong`), in the same file where virtual hosts are configured:

```
FastCgiConfig -appConnTimeout 2
```

This was to tell the server to wait no more than 2 seconds, instead of the 30 seconds it was waiting. I tried to invoked a FastCGI script to see if at least this configuration was working. I expected to get an error in a 2 seconds delay, but instead, the script ran without error.

What's weird, is that I then tried to remove this option, to check if it was just that addition which was just missing to make FastCGI scripts working. But after I commented‑out the option, it was still working, and the same after a full reboot.

Can't tell more, that looks weird, but this is the only thing I did, I did not edit anything else. I can just suggest people who may encounter a similar issue, to just try the above.

Sorry, if I can't explain what it did exactly. I really would like to know. It just working now, but I don't know why.

Comment: Finally it's not always working. There is still an issue. See the initial message which was update to tell about this new issue. My answer to my own question is only partial so far.

Comment: Finally OK (see first post). The answer, although it does not tell how, really was enough to solve the case.

Answer (score 2):

#############

fastcgi.conf 
   FastCgiWrapper Off

Answer (score 0):

peng.rl 's answer solve my problem.

My ceph radosgw can't get apache's input at all. after set FastCgiWrapper Off, I can capture data in wireshark.